# Cartoon about manned robots that would drive instead of walk

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots, cartoon

I used to watch this show in, possibly, the late 90s, about manned robots that were operated by humans. Kind of like the machines in the *Avatar* movie, however, they didn't really walk but instead drove and were fast. If I can remember correctly, there were good guys and bad guys. They were either at war or racing each other. The graphics were fairly decent, resembled the *Beast Wars* graphics, but I could be wrong. Watched in East Coast USA.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: When you say "graphics", does that mean the show was CG? If so, was it all like that, or only the robots?

Answer (score 3):

This could be practically anything given the vague details, from *Mask* to a variety of *Transformers* based shows but given the details so far I'm going to plump for [*Robotix*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0243726/), because it's a little more obscure.

This was a film and TV show from the late 80s.

[image: Robotix and Humans]

As per the question, there were good guys (Protectorons) and bad guys (Terrakors). The Protectorons and Terrakors lived on a planet that went through some bad times. They were converted into computer data and eventually uploaded into "Robotix", giant machines that they would use to rebuild following the disaster.

The Robotix weren't supposed to be inhabited by computer version of the aliens, they were supposed to be driven, which is where the Humans (Crash landed in the film) come in. They can operate the control cabins of each robot, upping their capabilities.

While they can walk around, they spend most of the time in their vehicle modes, racing about.

The good guys and bad guys were, of course, at war. More details can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotix).

Answer (score 2):

If it's more about the racing aspect, I'd give it to [Heavy Gear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Gear#TV_series)

There are 2 competing teams who's power balance gets upset as a new driver join the "good" team. This new driver turns out to be an ace pilot.

The good team is called the Shadow Dragons and the bad team is called The Vanguard of Justice.

This series played at around the time of Beast Wars.

Here's an example on Youtube

Comment: Given the comparison to "Beast Wars graphics", Heavy Gear is almost definitely it. Right around the same era of 3DCG mecha.

Answer (score 1):

There are some similarities to **IGPX: Immortal Grand Prix**.

> *...manned robots that were operated by humans... **they didn't really walk but instead drove and were fast**. ...They were either at war or **racing each other***.

> **In the IGPX, two teams of three mechs, high-tech fighting machines driven by humans, race at speeds greater than 350 mph (560 km/h).** The IGPX also contains fighting elements; attacking the opposing team to disable their mechs (thus preventing them from winning the race) is not only legal, but also expected. Team Satomi, a crew of amateur pilots, has just won a minor-league championship, the IG-2, vaulting them into the sport’s highest level, the IG-1. Now, the untested rookies of Team Satomi must overcome impossible odds and beat the world’s most skilled and ruthless pilots.
>   <sup>-[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortal_Grand_Prix)</sup>

However IGPX aired in *2005* and there was no war - just racing.